# Javascript taking too long to run

Tags: javascript

I have a script that is taking too long to run and that is causing me This error on ie : a script on this page is causing internet explorer to run slowly.

I have read other threads concerning this error and have learned that there is a way to by pass it by putting a time out after a certain number of iterations.

Can u help me apply a time out on the following function please ?

Basically each time i find a hidden imput of type submit or radio i want to remove and i have a lot of them . Please do not question why do i have a lots of hidden imputs. I did it bc i needed it just help me put a time out please so i wont have the JS error. Thank you

```
$('input:hidden').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if($("[name='"+name+"']").length >1){
        if($(this).attr('type')!=='radio' && $(this).attr('type')!=='submit'){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }
  });
```

One of the exemples i found : [Bypassing IE's long-running script warning using setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655301/bypassing-ies-long-running-script-warning-using-settimeout)

Comment: Stop doing `$(this)`, instead, assign it to a variable

Comment: Dude read the code please before commenting, putting $this in a variable or leaving it like that changes nothing.

Comment: How many inputs do you have to make such a small script "long-running"?

Comment: learn pure javascript. the `.each()` loop can be up 90% slower than pure javascript `for` loop

Comment: Thank you Jay , yes you are 100 %  right about that i will swap it with a norma for loop for extra performance.

Comment: @user2515601 [Dude it does change something](http://jsperf.com/jquery-whatever)

Comment: well ok it does :). Thank you for the example.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to add `input` to your jquery selector to filter out only input tags.

```
if($("input[name='"+name+"']").length >1){
```

Comment: Perfect :). Althought i wanted to learn how to time out it to bypass the error. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's the same code optimised a bit without (yet) using `setTimeout()`:

```
var $hidden = $('input:hidden'),
    el;
for (var i = 0; i < $hidden.length; i++) {
  el = $hidden[i];
  if(el.type!=='radio' && el.type!=='submit'
             && $("[name='" + el.name + "']").length >1) {

     $(el).remove();
  }
}
```

Notice that now there is a maximum of three function calls per iteration, whereas the original code had up to ten function calls per iteration. There's no need for, say, `$(this).attr('type')` (two function calls) when you can just say `this.type` (no function calls).

Also, the `.remove()` only happens if three conditions are true, the two `type` tests and check for other elements of the same name. Do the `type` tests *first,* because they're quick, and only bother doing the slow check for other elements if the `type` part passes. (JS's `&&` doesn't evaluate the right-hand operand if the left-hand one is falsy.)

Or with `setTimeout()`:

```
var $hidden = $('input:hidden'),
    i = 0,
    el;
function doNext() {
   if (i < $hidden.length) {
      el = $hidden[i];
      if(el.type!=='radio' && el.type!=='submit'
                && $("[name='" + el.name + "']").length >1) {

         $(el).remove();
      }
      i++;
      setTimeout(doNext, 0);
   }
}
doNext();
```

You could improve either version by changing `$("[name='" + el.name + "']")` to specify a specific element type, e.g., if you are only doing inputs use `$("input[name='" + el.name + "']")`. Also you could limit by some container, e.g., if those inputs are all in a form or something.

Comment: The answer i was looking for and more. Thank you sir

Comment: user2515601, you should mark @nnnnnn's as the best answer...since it is.  :)

Comment: Thank you user2515601 and @David. I just tweaked my answer a bit more, changing the order of the `if` test conditions so that the slow one is only evaluated if the others pass. (Note that I didn't actually test any of that code, but it should be clear enough to give you the idea...)

Comment: I'd rather optimize by omitting the jQuery call - `document.getElementsByName(el.name).length` (though there are bugs in older browsers)

Comment: for even better optimization change `(var i = 0; i < $hidden.length; i++)` to `(var i = 0, len = $hidden.length; i < len; i++)`.. this will prevent the loop from evaluating the length of the element on every iteration

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the example you cited is exactly what you need.  I think if you take your code and replace the `while` loop in the example (keep the `if` statement for checking the batch size), you're basically done.  You just need the jQuery version of breaking out of a loop.

Comment: Though the long-running-loop might be inside the `$('input:hidden')` already…

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("[type=hidden]").remove(); // at the place of each loop
```

It will take a short time to delete all hidden fields.

I hope it will help.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sonusindhu/F9JKv/)

Comment: But the OP's code doesn't delete only `type="hidden"` fields. The `:hidden` selector also returns things hidden with CSS. And the OP's code does a test based on each element's `name`...

Comment: it will delete all hidden fields which has hidden type <input type="hidden">

Answer (score 1):

To risk stating the obvious; traversing through the DOM looking for matches to these CSS selectors is what's making your code slow. You can cut down the amount of work it's doing with a few simple tricks:

Are these fields inside a specific element? If so you can narrow the search by including that element in the selector.

e.g:

```
$('#container input:hidden').each(function(){
    ...
```

You can also narrow the number of fields that are checked for the `name` attribute

e.g:

```
if($("#container input[name='"+name+"']").length >1){
```

I'm also unclear why you're searching *again* with `$("[name='"+name+"']").length >1`once you've found the hidden element. You didn't explain that requirement. If you don't need that then you'll speed this up hugely by taking it out.

```
$('#container input:hidden').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if($(this).attr('type')!=='radio' && $(this).attr('type')!=='submit'){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

If you **do** need it, and I'd be curious to know why, but the best approach might be to restructure the code so that it only checks the number of inputs for a given name once, and removes them all in one go.